# Why are learning sibling cards not buried?

Tags: anki

I am learning how to use Anki to learn Japanese. The Anki manual says that when you rate a card, its new/learned siblings will be buried but not its learning siblings because time is of the essence for learning siblings. Could someone please better explain the "time is of the essence" justification? Thank you. Also, why is it that you can bury a learning card but Anki won't bury a learning card when you rate its sibling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just saying that if you've just started learning a card you can't skip it or the effort you've already put in is likely to be wasted, the reason being that whatever mental links you are starting to establish are still very weak. If you haven't seen it yet you can obviously put it off no problem, and if you basically know it you can put reviews off and still catch up later - you're not going to forget it completely - but at the very early stages you need the repetition or you will forget it completely and end up starting again from scratch. In other words, the learning phase of the process is the most time-sensitive.